# Why does my validation loss increase, but validation accuracy perfectly matches training accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, convolutional-neural-network

I am building a simple 1D convolutional neural network in Keras. Here is the model:

```
def build_model():

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.SeparableConv1D(64, kernel_size=2, activation="relu", input_shape=(64,20)))
    model.add(layers.SeparableConv1D(64, kernel_size=2, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(4))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

    model.compile(
        optimizer='rmsprop',
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=[
            keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
        ],
    )
    
    #model.summary()
    
    return model
```

When I train my model on roughly 1500 samples, I always get my training and validation accuracy completely overlapping and virtually equal, reflected in the graph below. This is making me think there is something fishy going on with my code or in Keras/Tensorflow since the loss is increasing dramatically and you would expect the accuracy to be affected at least somewhat by this. It looks like it is massively overfitting and yet only reporting the accuracy values for the training set or something along those lines. When I then test on a test set, the accuracy is nowhere near the 85 to 90 percent reported on the graph, but rather ~70%.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this for the longest time. Below is the training code.

[image]

```
#Define the number of folds... this will give us an 80/20 split
k = 5
epochs = 100
num_val_samples = len(x_train) // k
scores_binacc = []
scores_precision = []
scores_recall = []
histories = []

#Train the dense model in k iterations
for i in range(k):
    print('Processing fold #', i)
    val_data = x_train[i * num_val_samples : (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
    val_targets = y_train[i * num_val_samples : (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
    
    print('Validation partition =  ', i * num_val_samples, (i + 1) * num_val_samples)
    print('Training partition 1 = ', 0, i * num_val_samples)
    print('Training partition 2 = ', (i+1) * num_val_samples, len(x_train))
    
    partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
        [
            x_train[:i * num_val_samples],
            x_train[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]
        ], 
        axis=0
    )
    
    partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
        [
            y_train[:i * num_val_samples],
            y_train[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]
        ],
        axis=0
    )
    
    model = build_model()
    h = model.fit(
        partial_train_data, 
        partial_train_targets, 
        validation_data=(val_data, val_targets),
        epochs=epochs, 
        verbose=1
    )
    
    val_loss, val_binacc = model.evaluate(val_data, val_targets, verbose=0)
    scores_binacc.append(val_binacc)
    #scores_precision.append(val_precision)
    #scores_recall.append(val_recall)
    histories.append(h)
```

Comment: I'm confused, is the second graph produced with the CV code at the end? As far as I understand this code would produce only 5 points, not a point for every number of epochs. Did you try without  using CV to simplify? That could be easier to investigate. Also you seem to have tried to look at precision/recall (commented), what did you observe?

Comment: @Erwan There are 5 (0-4) training/validation folds.

Comment: @DerekH Yes I got that, but to draw a curve like the one on the second graph you need a point for every epoch and every fold. I don't see how this code gives you the value for every epoch, since the loop is only for 0..4.

Comment: Hey @Erwan, `model.fit` is run within the loop body, which is the actual training method-- you can see the epochs specified within the loop that as you have pointed out runs five times. So, a total of 5 training sessions with 100 epochs per session gives a curve with five lines, 100 epochs long